# Best way to check whether a cloud formation stack exists using AWS Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-java-sdk

what is the best way to check whether a stack exists using the AWS Java SDK, given a stack name?

I've tried the below code based on - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsCloudFormation/CloudFormationSample.java

```
    DescribeStacksRequest wait = new DescribeStacksRequest();
    wait.setStackName(stackName);        
    List<Stack> stacks = awsCFTClient.describeStacks(wait).getStacks();
    if (stacks.isEmpty()) {
        logger.log("NO_SUCH_STACK");
        return true;
    }
```

However, I am getting:

AmazonServiceException:com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.model.AmazonCloudFormationException: Stack with id "stackName" does not exist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the stack doesn't exist you won't be able to Describe it to check if it exists or not. So you can solve that issue by a simple try-catch. Catch the AmazonCloudFormationException. Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is looking for a quick and dirty solution, this works,

```
//returns true if stack exists
public boolean stackExists(AmazonCloudFormation awsCFTClient, String stackName) throws Exception{
    DescribeStacksRequest describe = new DescribeStacksRequest();
    describe.setStackName(stackName);
    //If stack does not exist we will get an exception with describe stack
    try {
        awsCFTClient.describeStacks(describe).getStacks();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        if (e.getMessage().matches("(.*)" + stackName + "(.*)does not exist(.*)")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If there is a better way for doing this, please let me know.

Comment: So far all I have found for this specific task is what you show here. For example: https://gist.github.com/mdjnewman/b9d722188f4f9c6bb277a37619665e77

Comment: However, if you want to know whether the stack exists so you can create vs. update it, as **abdennour** comments on the above-referenced gist, if you are using the AWS CLI, `aws cloudformation deploy` solves the problem nicely. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html

Comment: you don't need parentheses around `.*` in regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Found a slightly better way to do it but with a few remarks:

- aws java sdk 2.0 is used here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2
- in the example below, you see kotlin syntax

  `client.listStacks().stackSummaries().any{ it.stackName() == stackName }`

In Java you can simply replace `any` method `anyMatch`.

According to the shallow check of the former aws java sdk 1.0 there is also `listStacks()` method in AmazonCLoudFormationClient class which does the same.

But in my case, I needed to filter those stacks (because if the stack has status DELETED... it will still appear in the list above) based on the status. So probably overloaded method will be more useful:

```
@Override
    public ListStacksResult listStacks(ListStacksRequest request) {
        request = beforeClientExecution(request);
        return executeListStacks(request);
    }
```